# No encuentro error en programa de Sign Up y Log In en Java

Tags: java

Estaba creando un programa en el cual se pedía un usuario y una contraseña, simulando un registro, y luego se procedía a simular un *login*.

En la etapa del registro, pido la contraseña dos veces(como es común en redes sociales), lo hago a través de un condicional `if`-`else` dentro de un `while`. Al tratar de compilarlo me da error supuestamente en la línea 36, que es la del `else`, pero no encuentro el error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EqualsPrueba{
  public static void main(String args[]){


  Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


   String Usuario = "";
   String Password = "";
   String Password2 = "";
   String CheckUsuario = "";
   String CheckPassword = "";
   int Confirmacion = 0;

   System.out.println("Bienvenido, primero debes registrarte");


   System.out.print("Ingresa tu nombre de usuario");
   Usuario = entrada.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Ingresa tu password");
   Password = entrada.nextLine();

   while(Confirmacion == 0){

     System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu password");
     Password2 = entrada.nextLine();

       if(Password2.equals(Password));{

         System.out.println("Te has registrado con exito");
         Confirmacion = Confirmacion + 1;    
    }
       else{

         System.out.println("Tus password no coinciden, por favor vuelve a intentarlo");
    }
  }

   System.out.println("Ahora debes iniciar sesion");
   Confirmacion = 0;



     while(Confirmacion == 0){

       System.out.print("Ingresa tu nombre de usuario"); 
       CheckUsuario = entrada.nextLine();      
       System.out.print("Ingresa tu password");
       CheckPassword = entrada.nextLine();

       if(CheckUsuario.equals(Usuario) && CheckPassword.equals(Password)){

         System.out.println("Has iniciado sesion correctamente");
         Confirmacion = Confirmacion + 1;
    }
       else{

         System.out.println("Usuario y/o password incorrectos, vuelve a intentar");  
    }
  }  
 }
}
```

Comment: Justo despues de publicar la pregunta encuentro el error... en la sentencia  if(Password2.equals(Password));{ sobra el punto y coma, deberia ser asi:
 if(Password2.equals(Password)){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota que al final de password2.equals(password) tienes *";"* intenta quitarlo o bien reemplazalo con el codigo que te comparto.

```
   while(Confirmacion == 0){

     System.out.print("Vuelve a escribir tu password");
     Password2 = entrada.nextLine();

       if(Password2.equals(Password)){

         System.out.println("Te has registrado con exito");
         Confirmacion = Confirmacion + 1;    
    }
       else{

         System.out.println("Tus password no coinciden, por favor vuelve a intentarlo");
    }
  }
```